# How to save time data to a variable in python

Tags: python, datetime

this code works but I cant save the first datetime entry

```
import csv
import sys
import datetime

f = open(sys.argv[1], 'rt')

now = datetime.datetime.now()
timeStart = str(now)


try:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        #Do stuff 
    timeStop = str(now)
    print str(timeStart)
    print timeStop
    print count

finally:
    f.close()
```

The problem is TimeStart and TimeStop agree so I cant really test how long the program has been running advise?

Comment: probably want a timer meant for code: https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html

Comment: datetime.datetime.now() returns a time, your timeStop is a str copy of the previous time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`now = datetime.datetime.now()` stores the current time in a variable called `now`. Later on, you're not asking `datetime` "What is the current time?", you're looking at the variable you stored the time in earlier on.

It's like looking at the clock and writing down that you started work at 9am, and then when you leave work, looking at the bit of paper, not the clock.

```
time_stop = datetime.datetime.now()
```

Answer (score 1):

At `now = datetime.datetime.now()` you pass the time at that point in time into the `now` variable, where it is stored. It's a constant. It won't change the next time you print `now`. If you want it to update you have to get the current time again. So you need `timeStop = str(datetime.datetime.now())`.